# Event Bindings not working with arrow keys Pycharm

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to do some basic animation to this triangle (I'm kinda new to coding) with event bindings where if I press an arrow key the triangle will move in that direction, and if I press enter key It will move to the right.

When I try to run the code, the 'enter' key moves the triangle, but the arrow keys do not. I copied this down from the book I am reading for python. Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

(Edit: I put in the wrong code sorry)

```
from tkinter import*
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_polygon(10, 10, 10, 60, 50, 35)


def movetriangle(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        canvas.move(1, 0, -3)
    elif event.keysym == 'Down':
        canvas.move(1, 0, 3)
    elif event.keysym == 'Left':
        canvas.move(1, -3, 0)
    else:
        canvas.move(1, 3, 0)


canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Return>', movetriangle)
tk.mainloop()
```

I want the arrow keys to animate the triangle, but there seems to be an error in my code.

Could someone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: You're only binding to the Return key. Take a look at the `bind_all` command.

Comment: Is the movetriangle not being binded @BryanOakley?

Comment: `movetriangle` is being bound to the return key only. That's what `<KeyPress-Return>` means.

Comment: If you want to stick to your current approach, you need to bind to `<Key>` instead, and also change the else statement to `elif event.keysym == 'Right':`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to key at the bottom instead of  and also add

```
elif event.keysym == 'Down'
```

and the other arrow keys or other characters if needed.